# Inclusion–exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Find the number of solutions to this equation:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6= 20$$
$$1\leq x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_6 \leq 4 $$

I know that at the start we need to define:

$y_1=x_1-1$

$y_2=x_2-1$

$y_3=x_3-1$

$y_4=x_4-1$

$y_5=x_5-1$

$y_6=x_6-1$

So we end up with this:

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_5=14$$

and now I need to use the "Inclusion–exclusion principle" but how?

Comment: Did you mean to say that each $x_1, \ldots, x_6$ is an integer between 1 and 4 inclusive?

Comment: For the start, we want $y_i=x_i-1$.

Comment: @Sasha Yes that what I mean

Comment: I would suggest $z_i = 4-x_i$ instead.

Comment: @CalvinLin  What is z?

Comment: A change of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each solution set $x_i$, we consider the change of variables $ z_i = 4 - x_i$.

Then, the conditions become $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 = 4$ and $0 \leq z_i \leq 3$.

Ignoring the upper bound on $z_i$, there are ${ 6+4 - 1 \choose 4 } =126$ solutions by the [technique Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/stars-and-bars/).

There are 6 solutions where (at least) one of $z_i$ is strictly greater than 3. By the Inclusion and Exclusion principle, there are 120 solutions in total.

---

Of course, you could apply the [technique PIE](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/) directly initially, but that is slightly tedious. Though that can be good practice too. Let $P_i$ be the sets of solutions where $x_i \geq 5$. Observe that at most 3 of them can be greater than or equal to 5.

Recall that the number of **positive** integer solutions by stars and bars to

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = n $$

is ${n-1 \choose 5} $. Let's evaluate $|P_i|, |P_i \cap P_j|$ and $|P_i \cap P_j \cap P_k|$.

$P_1$ corresponds to solutions with $x_1 \geq 5$. using the change of variables $a_1 = 4 + x_1$, we thus have

$$ a_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4+ x_5 + x_6 = 16. $$

There are ${ 15 \choose 5}$ solutions in this case.

Similarly, $|P_i \cap P_j| = {11 \choose 5}, |P_i \cap P_j \cap P_k | = {7 \choose 5}$.

Hence, by PIE,

$$|\cup P_i | = {6 \choose 1} {15 \choose 5} - { 6\choose 2} { 11 \choose 5} + {6 \choose 3} { 7 \choose 5} = 11508.$$

Hence, the number of solutions is ${19 \choose 5 } - 11508 = 120 $ (Phew!)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to solve this linear equation is to (by using the formula $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_r=n\implies\dbinom{n+r-1}{r-1}$)
We know that $x_i\geq1$ so we will subtract the minimum value from the equation assuming that all $x_i=x_i'+1$ and moving forward with that we get:$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_6=14$$ now we calculate the number of all integer solutions in this restriction (then we will move forward with the second one):$$\dbinom{14+6-1}{6-1}=\dbinom{19}{5}$$ and then we substitude values for $x_i$ as $4$ and subtract the situations because we use $\geq\square$ and subtract it from all the number of solutions in order to get $\leq\square$ moving on; 
$$x_1'+4+x_2+\cdots+x_6=14\implies 6\dbinom{10+6-1}{6-1}$$ (Because we repeat this for all $6$ variables) and then when two of them are $x_k'+4$ we say:$$x_1'+4+x_2'+4+x_3+\cdots+x_6=14\implies\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{6+6-1}{6-1}$$
For three variables: $$x_1'+x_2'+x_3'+12+\cdots+x_6=14\implies\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{2+6-1}{6-1}$$ This is where we stop because if we keep going with $4$ variables we end up in a situation where $x_k\leq0$ and we don't want that because we have established a position like $x_k\geq0$ after we subtracted the $1$s. So now we combine these situations with inclusion-exclusion principle, which basically makes us put $-$ and $+$ after another, but we start with $-$ because we are subtracting: $$\dbinom{19}{5}-6\dbinom{15}{5}+\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{11}{5}-\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{7}{5}=120$$